# What are the conditions for shiny::observeEvent to work or break, i. e., to isolate its arguments

Tags: r, shiny

In my understanding, `observeEvent` treats everything in the `handlerExpr` as if they were wrapped in an `isolate` function, so it should only be triggered when an input or `reactiveValue` in the `eventExpr` is invalidated (changed) (entirely not paraphrasing @divibisan here).

In this shiny app with an action button, this sometimes works, and sometimes doesn't. Can someone explain, why this is the case. (parts of the code was taken from [RStudio Website](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/overview.html) assuming they are ok with me doing this.

This app will plot two identical barplots of the population of the selected country when the **Go** button is pressed. My experience is that after the first press of the **Go** button, both diagrams will be rendered. Going further, the top diagram will instantly update, ignoring the button (# case 1 - action button broken), while the 2nd diagram only updates on button event as intended (# case 2 - action only when Go-button is pressed).

1. Can you reproduce this behavior?
2. Why is that, and what the rules?
3. I seem not to understand.

.

```
library(shiny)
library(DBI)
library(pool)
library(dplyr)
library(dbplyr)
library(forcats)
library(ggplot2)

pool <- dbPool(
  drv = RMySQL::MySQL(),
  dbname = "shinydemo",
  host = "shiny-demo.csa7qlmguqrf.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com",
  username = "guest",
  password = "guest"
)

query <- function(inp){
  pool %>%
    tbl("Country") %>%
    select(Code,Name) %>%
    rename(CountryName = Name) %>%
    filter(CountryName == !!inp) %>%
    left_join(.,pool %>%
                tbl("City"),by = c("Code" ="CountryCode")) %>%
    select(CountryName, Name,Population) %>% arrange(desc(Population)) %>%
    collect()
}

gplot <- function(x){
  ggplot2::ggplot(x %>% mutate(Name = fct_reorder(Name,Population,.desc=TRUE)),aes(x=Name,y=Population)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +     
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) 
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("selectcountry", label = h3(""), 
              choices = as.list( pool %>% tbl("Country") %>% pull(Name))),
  actionButton("do", label ="Go" ),
  htmlOutput("actionbuttoncounter"),
  plotOutput("popPlot"),
  plotOutput("popPlot2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  session$onSessionEnded(function(){pool::poolClose(pool)})

  output$actionbuttoncounter <- renderText(input$do)
  observeEvent(input$do, {

    # case 1 - action button broken
    output$popPlot <- renderPlot({
      query(inp = input$selectcountry) %>% gplot()
    })
    # case 2 - action only when Go-button is pressed
     result <- query(inp = input$selectcountry)
     output$popPlot2<- renderPlot({
       gplot(result)
     })
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**UPDATE**

this has nothing to do with dbplyr, so a minimal example would be this:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
gplot <- function(x){
  hist(x)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("num", label = h3("Numeric input"), value = 1),
  actionButton("do", label ="Go" ),
  htmlOutput("actionbuttoncounter"),
  plotOutput("popPlot"),
  plotOutput("popPlot2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {


  output$actionbuttoncounter <- renderText(input$do)
  observeEvent(input$do, {
    # case 1 - action button broken
    output$popPlot <- renderPlot({
      rnorm(input$num) %>% gplot()
    })
    # case 2 - propper action
    result <- rnorm(input$num)
    output$popPlot2<- renderPlot({
     result %>% gplot()
    })
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Additional info

```
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Mojave 10.14.6

locale:
[1] de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8/C/de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_3.2.0 forcats_0.4.0 dbplyr_1.4.2  dplyr_0.8.3   pool_0.1.4.2  DBI_1.1.0     shiny_1.4.0
```

Comment: In shiny, the `render*` functions build reactive objects to display on UI. So, even though you have a Go button requirement the fact that you are calling `input$num` inside a `renderPlot()` functions makes it reactive. Also, you mentioned that case 1 action button broken. I don't think that is what happening, for every Go button click, you can see the plot axis are changing. So, it is rendering plot for every click.

Comment: For the second plot, you are storing the `input$num` in a result object outside the `renderPlot` function. If you need to replicate the same behavior as plot 1, you would need to wrap it in a reactive function `result <- reactive(rnorm(input$num))` and call it `result() %>% gplot()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with @user5249203. Would advise not including `output` rendering from within `observeEvent` (this is not needed to work).

Here is one approach that updates a `reactive` value every time the button is pressed. The plots will automatically update when the data changes.

Does this have the behavior you were looking for?

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  rv <- reactiveVal()

  output$actionbuttoncounter <- renderText(input$do)

  observeEvent(input$do, {
    rv(rnorm(input$num))
  })

  output$popPlot <- renderPlot({
    if (is.null(rv())) return ()
    gplot(rv())
  })

  output$popPlot2 <- renderPlot({
    if (is.null(rv())) return ()
    gplot(rv())
  })

}
```

Comment: Using reactiveVals was my usual way to do it, and now I know why it the proper way to do things. So I take away that `render*` breaks isolation. Thx